# Creating and Showing PDF's within Windows 8 store App

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

I want to create a Windows 8 store app which will allow me to create and show a PDF to a user based on information they have inputted. In the new Windows 8.1 framework there is a built in API to show the PDF documents however I am not sure how to create them.

My initial thinking was to save the PDF file as HTML text (In Azure) and create the PDF document using something like iTextStart. However this wont work in Windows 8 store apps.

Is it actually possible to create the PDF document within the application or will I need to host a full .net application somewhere which could return the PDF document as an image. (I assume a web service would then need to be used to retrieve the image)

Comment: That isn't exactly a task that's suitable for a store app.  Your program goes off the woods for a while and you'll get suspended when the user tires of waiting and switches to Solitaire.  Certainly best to have this done by a web service.

Comment: I thought that would be the case. Is it best to return as an image file through a web service or a PDF. Taking into consideration speed etc,